# How to plot for imported data while performing some operations on different columns?

Tags: plotting, import

I have imported an Excel file, then I did multiplied different numbers with different columns;

```
Data=Import["file"][[1]];

Convert={1,25,37}#&/Data;

PM23= sqrt[(Convert[[All,2]])^2+(Convert[[All,3]])^2];
```

Now, I want to plot First column with 2, and 3 column separately, So for I have tried;

```
M = ListLinePlot[Convert[[All, {1, PM23}]], AxesLabel -> {"Qk", "M"}]
```

But, it didn't work. Any help will appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [`Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html). Part takes location indices and `PM23` is not a list of indices.  Even if it were you syntax would still be incorrect.

You need to construct the two data series, see [`ListLinePlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListLinePlot.html).  Something like the following show work.

```
ListLinePlot[Transpose@{Convert[[All, 1]], #} & /@ Transpose@PM23, AxesLabel -> {"Qk", "M"}]
```

Hope this helps.